# How to generate download link?

Tags: python, django, file-upload, django-views, django-templates

I'm triying to create a link to download file which has been uploaded.

models.py

```
class Comentario (models.Model):

    archivo = models.FileField(upload_to='media', null=True, blank=True)
```

settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL='/media/'
```

template.html

```
<a href="{{ MEDIA_URL }} {{detail.archivo.url}}" download>Descargar</a>
```

views.py

```
  def ComentarioListar(request):
     form2 = ComentarioForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
     if request.method == 'POST' and form2.is_valid():
        form2.instance.autor = request.user
        form2.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/listar')

objects= Comentario.objects.filter(tag__in=bb).exclude(autor__id=request.user.id)[:5]

return render(request, 'home/comentario_listar.html', {'objects': objects,  'form2':form2})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^download/(?P<filename>.+)$', login_required(views.download), name='download')]
```

When I click the download link it does not download the .jpg saved in 'media' folder. Is the path incorrectly specified? It is necessary to create a special view for that?

Comment: Right-click on the `a` element and inspect it. What is the value of `href`?

Comment: now my value is 127.0.0.1:8000/media/

Comment: Would you mind to show your `views.py` where the `detail` is passed into the template?

Comment: I have edited my question, you can see ther views.py and urls.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are passing a Queryset of Comentario objects through to your template as 'objects', but you then aren't referencing 'objects' at all in your template.

Here's an example of how you could pull a list of URLs for each object in your 'objects' Queryset. Here, we iterate through each object in the 'objects' Queryset, and pull its archivo.url out into the template:

**comentario_listar.html**

```
{% for object in objects %}
    <a href="{{ object.archivo.url }}">Descargar</a>
{% endfor %}
```

---

Note that if you wanted, you could also pass comentario_listar.html a single object and render that object's URL like so:

**views.py**

```
def ComentarioListar(request):
     form2 = ComentarioForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
     if request.method == 'POST' and form2.is_valid():
        form2.instance.autor = request.user
        form2.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/listar')

    // Create a variable called 'detail' that references just one Comentario object, and pass it to the comentario_listar.html template
    detail = Comentario.objects.all()[0]

    return render(request, 'home/comentario_listar.html', {'detail': detail,  'form2':form2}
```

**comentario_listar.html**

```
<a href="{{detail.archivo.url}}" download>Descargar</a>
```

Comment: I have inspected it, and href is /media/. But "{{ detail.archivo.url }}" does not work, so could be that i'm not passin detail through my context. How can I do that?7

Comment: It sounds like the 'detail' object is not being passed through to your template in views.py. Could you show us the section of views.py where you render your template?

Comment: I have edited my question, you can see ther views.py and urls.py

Comment: JohnWire - to clarify, we'll need to see the section of views.py that serves template.html, not the section that serves your download. Could you show us the code that you use to render template.html?

Comment: here you have, I have to filter 'archivo' there?

Comment: Thanks! I've edited my answer above — see if that change solves your problem.